# Execute delete() within save() in Django

Tags: django, model, save, sql-delete, wagtail

I'm working on a Django/Wagtail project. I'm trying to build a very customized feature that requires an object to be deleted when hitting the Save button when certain conditions are met.

I override the Save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if condition:
        return super(ArticleTag, self).delete()

    else:
        return super(ArticleTag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know this looks very odd and completely anti-adviseable, but it is exactly the behavior I'm trying to achieve.

Is there a better or "correct" way to do this?

Are there other steps to exactly reproduce the behavior as if the user had hit Delete directly?

Comment: if you implement a signal receiver should be a better solution. because your don't put more code in your model class.

Comment: @Gytree could you show how that'd be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the object already exists in your db, you can do as follows:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if condition:
        self.delete() # you do not need neither to return the deleted object nor to call the super method. 
    else:
        return super(ArticleTag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This worked! But I'm facing a new issue, would you check this question? ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824630/redirect-to-delete-view-in-django-admin

Answer (score 0):

Using signals receivers

> signals.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

__all__ = ['check_delete_condition']

@receiver(post_save, sender="yourapp.yourmodel")
def check_delete_condition(instance, raw, created, using, updatefields, **kwargs):
    if condition:
        instance.delete()
```

in your apps.py you can't put the signals import

```
from .signals import *

#rest of code
```